# Translate a while loop into for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

Have a simple while loop and trying to make it to a for loop

```
i=1
while(i<=128)
{     printf("%d",i);
   i*=2;
}
```

Here is my for loop

```
for (i=1;i<=128;i++)
{ 
   printf("%d",i);
   i*=2;
}
```

How come it does not give the same output? The first one would print `1248163264128`, the for loop print `137153163127`?

Comment: Increment `i*=2` in `for (i=1;i<=128;i*=2)`

Comment: condition in for loop is wrong.. Placing i*=2 in place of i++ solves your issue..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're also incrementing `i` in the for-loop. In your original while-loop, `i` is never incremented.

Try this:

```
for (i=1; i<=128; i*=2)  //  Remove i++, move the i*=2 here.
{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Comment: No, by all means try this `for(i=1; i<=128; i*=2)`! Even worse, this answer strengthens the idea that a for loop can only increment a loop variable, which the OP seems to have already.

Comment: @ChristianRau Looks like you've stumbled upon a post from my earlier days. Fixed.

Answer (score 13):

The `for` loop doubles `i` and then increments it. The `while` loop only doubles it.

Change the `for` loop to this:

```
for (i=1;i<=128;i*=2) {
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i=1;i<=128;i*=2)
{ 
  printf("%d",i);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `while` loop you didn't increment `i`, but in your `for` loop you are using

```
for (i=1;i<=128;i++)
{
printf("%d",i);
    i*=2;
}
```

You are incrementing `i` with one and multiplying `i` by 2 in each iteration of your loop. This is the reason you are getting weird result.

Try the following code for the same result as while loop is generating.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 128; i *= 2)
{
printf("%d",i);        
}
```